# drag and drop in radTreeListView

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik, mvvm-light

I am using two RadTreeListView contorls using Drag and Drop. Now my problem is that I can't drag the SubTreeList Item. I can only Drag The Root Item. I need to drag the sub items not the root item form the TreeListView.

Answer (score 2):

if IsDragDropEnabled="True"  for a telerik treeview. then all its elements are by default can be darged. in order to achieve customize behaviour like you want certain elements to be dragable and other should not be draged. you can handle PreviewDragStarted event of RadTreeview in code behind. if this event handler if u set e.handled = true then it will cancel the drag and voice versa.

```
 private void treeListView_PreviewDragStarted(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTreeViewDragEventArgs e)   
       {
        //do not allow portfolio group or product to be dragged
        if (e.DraggedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            object source = e.DraggedItems[0];
            if (source is parent)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```